# problemas con mostrar y ocultar boton javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, bootstrap

tengo el siguiente problema

Estoy ocultando botones, cuando se presiono un boton se oculta y se muestra otro, los estoy haciendo en una tabla con varios registros. el problema es que no todos los registros de la tabla me ocultan el boton solo en un registro que es el primero.

mostrare imagenes para que me entiendan mejor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el primer registro me funciona bien. 
pero cuando lo hago con otro registro de la tabla no me funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo de como lo hice

```js
//funcion para mostrar/ocultar los botones al momento del click
<script>
        var btn_1 = document.getElementById('btn-1');
        var btn_2 = document.getElementById('btn-2');
        
        function mostrarBoton2 () {
            btn_1.style.display = 'none';
            btn_2.style.display = 'inline';
        }
        function mostrarBoton1 () {
            btn_2.style.display = 'none';
            btn_1.style.display = 'inline';
        }
    </script>
```

```html
 <?php
       //llamar archivo de la conexion BD
      include "conexion.php";
      //sentencia select para traer datos desde la base
      $sql="SELECT ID_Usuario,Nombres,Apellidos,Identidad,correo,Usuario,Password,Nivel_Permiso FROM usuario";
      //metodo mysql
      $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
      //while para imprimir los datos en la tabla
      while($ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){

         //variable para capturar datos a mostrar en el form de edicion de usuarios
        $datos=$ver[0]."||".
               $ver[1]."||".
               $ver[2]."||".
               $ver[3]."||".
               $ver[4]."||".
               $ver[5]."||".
               $ver[7];
      ?>

          <tr> 
          <td><?php echo $ver[1]?></td>
          <td><?php echo $ver[2]?></td>
          <td><?php echo $ver[3]?></td>
          <td><?php echo $ver[4]?></td>
          <td><?php echo $ver[5]?></td>
          <td><?php echo $ver[7]?></td>
          <!--boton edicion-->
          <td>
          <button class="btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalEdicion" onclick="agregaform('<?php echo $datos ?>')">
          Editar
          </button>
          </td>
         <!--boton estado-->
--------///aqui es donde estan los botones del estado------
          <td>
          <button  type="button" class="btn btn-danger " id="btn-1"  onclick="mostrarBoton2()">Desactivar</button>
          <button  type="button" class="btn btn-success " id="btn-2" onclick="mostrarBoton1()" style="display: none;">Activar</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <?php  
      }
      ?>
      </tbody>
   </table>
```

gracias por sus respuestas :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

es porque todos comparten el mismo id... trata de agregar un counter

//funcion para mostrar/ocultar los botones al momento del click

```
    <script>


        function mostrarBoton2 (id) {
        var btn_1 = document.getElementById('btn-1-'+id);
        var btn_2 = document.getElementById('btn-2-'+id);
            btn_1.style.display = 'none';
            btn_2.style.display = 'inline';
        }
        function mostrarBoton1 () {
        var btn_1 = document.getElementById('btn-1-'+id);
        var btn_2 = document.getElementById('btn-2-'+id);
            btn_2.style.display = 'none';
            btn_1.style.display = 'inline';
        }
    </script>
<?php
   //llamar archivo de la conexion BD
  include "conexion.php";
  //sentencia select para traer datos desde la base
  $sql="SELECT ID_Usuario,Nombres,Apellidos,Identidad,correo,Usuario,Password,Nivel_Permiso FROM usuario";
  //metodo mysql
  $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
  //while para imprimir los datos en la tabla
  $counter = 0;
  while($ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){

     //variable para capturar datos a mostrar en el form de edicion de usuarios
    $datos=$ver[0]."||".
           $ver[1]."||".
           $ver[2]."||".
           $ver[3]."||".
           $ver[4]."||".
           $ver[5]."||".
           $ver[7];
  ?>

      <tr> 
      <td><?php echo $ver[1]?></td>
      <td><?php echo $ver[2]?></td>
      <td><?php echo $ver[3]?></td>
      <td><?php echo $ver[4]?></td>
      <td><?php echo $ver[5]?></td>
      <td><?php echo $ver[7]?></td>
      <!--boton edicion-->
      <td>
      <button class="btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalEdicion" onclick="agregaform('<?php echo $datos ?>')">
      Editar
      </button>
      </td>
     <!--boton estado-->
      --------///aqui es donde estan los botones del estado------
      <td>
      <button  type="button" class="btn btn-danger " id="btn-1-<?=$counter?>"  onclick="mostrarBoton2(<?=$counter?>)">Desactivar</button>
      <button  type="button" class="btn btn-success " id="btn-2-<?=$counter?>" onclick="mostrarBoton1(<?=$counter?>)" style="display: none;">Activar</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <?php  
  $counter++;
  }
  ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda me sirvio :)